# Is there any reason for using the word "column" in the context of one-dimensional tensor?

Tags: pytorch, terminology, tensor

Consider the following statements from the chapter named **[Tensors: Multidimensional arrays](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf#page=73)** from the textbook titled Deep Learning with PyTorch by *Eli Stevens et al*.

> Let’s construct our first PyTorch tensor and see what it looks like.
> It won’t be a particularly meaningful tensor for now, just three ones
> in a **column**:
>
> ```
> # In[4]:
> import torch
> a = torch.ones(3)
> a
> ```

In general, the notion of the column is used in the case of at least two dimensions. The tensor initialized is of a single dimension. So, I am guessing that it is *immaterial* if we use either row or column.

Am I true? Else, Is there any reason behind using the word "column" in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Often, in linear algebra theory, an `n`-dimensional vector is considered as a `n x 1` matrix, called a *column vector*.

Indeed, the behavior of a `tensor` `t` with shape `(n,)` is very similar to that of a `tensor` `u` of shape `(n, 1)`. In mathematical terms, you can think of a vector *t* in *R^n* and a vector *u* in *R^{n x 1}*.

In conclusion, the author, perhaps, is suggesting to treat the `tensor` as a mathematical column vector.